# Filter XML with 2 conditions using JOOX and XPATH (JAVA)

Tags: java, xml, parsing, xpath, joox

I have many xml files to filter and I need to do it with JOOX. I'm using it with XPATH to filter by one condition but I need at least two conditions, I would like to be a dynamic filtering to which I could add more filters if it's requested, but at least I need two. A priori I don't know the structure of the xml and maybe the two conditions reference to siblings nodes. The structures of my xml are like this:

```
<Message>
   <Header>
      <SequenceNumber>12345</SequenceNumber>
      <OriginSystem>xxx</OriginSystem>
      <Timestamp>141</Timestamp>
      <ContentType>123</ContentType>
   </Header>
   <OriginCenter>
      <CR id="xx" />
      <LI id="We" />
   </OriginCenter>
   <MessageType>
      <Type1 id="myId">
         <Id>LAV6.OIR.282O</Id>
         <TimeStampValue value="1430275652165" />
         <State>
            <UpToDate value="YES" />
            <InterlockedRoute value="YES" routeType="Itinerario" />
            <Sliding value="NOT" routeType="" />
            <Blocked value="NOT" />
            <Plaques>
               <PlaqueO value="NOT" counter="0" />
               <PlaqueV value="NOT" />
            </Plaques>
            <Dual value="YES" active="YES" />
         </State>
         <Flights number="1">
            <Flight index="1" Id="09070" />
         </Flights >
      </Type1>
   </MessageType>
   <Optionals>
      <Parameter1 name="" value="" />
      <Parameter2 name="" value="" />
      <Parameter3 name="" value="" />
   </Optionals>
</Message>
```

An example could be: find all the messages where **PlaqueV** has the property **value** with value **NOT** and **Blocked** has the property **value** with value **NOT**.

I would do it knowing the depth of the structure with xpath using: `//Blocked[@value='NOT']/../Plaques/PlaqueV[@value='NOT']`

How I could do it dinamically without knowing the structure?

Thanks!

Comment: Without knowing the structure it's a bit too much... if you don't know how deep is your element in the xml tree you can do as you already did, using double slash (//)

Comment: `Message[.//Blocked[@value='NOT'] and .//PlaqueV[@value='NOT']]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you splash58, I finally solved it creating a dynamic string and passing it to JOOX.

I mean: `JOOX.$(file).xpath(conditions);`

Where conditions is the dynamic string I created using your advice:

```
Root[.//TAG[@property='value'] and .//TAG[content='value'] and...]
```